# Alternating element's style using pseudo class that are in separate parents

Tags: css, html, pseudo-class, css-selectors

I have several `div` elements and I want to alternate another set of `div` styles within them. So basically change the child's style to alternating background colors like so:

*HTML*

```html
<article class="post"> <!--first post-->
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  content here
</article>

<article class="post"> <!--second post-->
  <div class="title">Title Here</div>
  content here
</article>
```

*CSS*

```css
div.title:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: #F00;
}
div.title:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color:#00F;
}
```

Is there a way to do this, because I know that using `css` to alternate styles it has to be within a parent. Or if not would there be any `jquery` script that i could use?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you do `article.post:nth-of-type(even) .title` [Works fine this way](http://jsfiddle.net/VMrDP/)

Comment: I posted this as an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
article.post:nth-of-type(even) .title
```

Works fine this way.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VMrDP/)**

---

Also, try to stay away from over-qualified CSS selectors like `div.title`, as explained in [this](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/) article by CSS Wizardy. Basically, the `.title` in this instance is definitely within the `article.post`, so you don't need to add the `div` too.

> Overqualified selectors make the browser work harder than it needs to 
>   and uses up its time; make your selectors leaner and more performant by 
>   cutting the unnecessary bits out.

Answer (score 1):

`nth-of-type` is alway checking for the postition of the element in his parent. Hence, your `div's` are always first child of `.post`. That's why it doesnt work.

But you can check the child position of it's parent. Just like that :

```
.post:nth-of-type(even) div.title{}
.post:nth-of-type(odd) div.title{}
```